# Timer in DOS batch file with actions

Tags: batch-file, dos

Can someone point me to a way to create a bat file that count the time and after certain hours perform an action?, And if you close it and open it again to continue where you left off.

Comment: Are you *really* using MS-DOS?

Comment: Perhaps you can play around with `%date%` and `%time%`. If you're really using MS-DOS, try your luck with `date` command.

Comment: Do you mean you want the script to resume from any point if restarted? Or just to keep waiting if before the action trigger time?

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrator privileges and the Task Scheduler is enabled you can use the `at` command:

Example Bat: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=atfuture_nt

Article explaining it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565